# Use of particle effect

Tags: libgdx

I am using particle effect my game using libgdx. But effect is showing for small time and after that it disappear.But I want to show my effect for long time or in my control.
My code is given below in my game play screen class...

```
ParticleEffectPool waterEffectPool;
Array<PooledEffect> effects = new Array<PooledEffect>();
ParticleEffect waterEffect;
...
...
waterEffect = new ParticleEffect();
    waterEffect.load(Gdx.files.internal("data/runonwater"), Gdx.files.internal("data"));
    waterEffectPool = new ParticleEffectPool(waterEffect, 1, 5);
    //for(int i = 0; i <= waterEffectPool.max; i++){
        PooledEffect effect = waterEffectPool.obtain();
        effect.setPosition(150, 130);
        effects.add(effect);
```

and in render method I use it to render

```
for(int i = effects.size - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        PooledEffect effect = effects.get(i);
        effect.draw(spriteBatch, deltaTime);
        if(effect.isComplete()){
            effect.free();
            effects.removeIndex(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using particle editor for this??? If yes then there is an option weather to set this effect continuous or not. set continuous as true and remove the code which uses effect.free() and effects.removeIndex(i).

Comment: @Pranav008 you are right. by set continuous true its working. thanks...

Comment: if its working then you can vote up. Thats how stackoverflow works :)

Comment: Actually, @Pranav008 you should give answers as "answers" and not as "comments".  Its okay to use a comment to find out if something basic is missing, but you should then add it as an answer so it can be "accepted". (You'll also get a lot more rep that way).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have already answered the question in the comments section above but still writing it here so as it can be accepted (as suggested by P.T.) 
If you are using particle editor then there is an option weather to set this effect **continuous** or not. Set continuous as true and problem will be solved .

@P.T. yups you r right. Will remember it from now on :)